# Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() method returns null, how can I fix it? I want to get screen width and heigth

Tags: java, screen, toolkit, dimension

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() method returns null, 
how can I fix it? I want to get screen width and height like this ->
Dimension screenSize = (Dimension) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
int creenHeight = screenSize.height;
int screenWidth = screenSize.width;

Comment: what is this? Java? Android?

Comment: This is java, java.awt.Toolkit class

Comment: Please post your code [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

```
GraphicsDevice monitors[]=GraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices(); 

Dimension screen_resolution[monitors.length];

for (int monitorID = 0; monitorID < monitors.length; monitorID++)
{
    screen_resolution[monitorID] = new Dimension(monitors[monitorID].getDisplyMode().getWidth(),monitors[monitorID].getDisplyMode().getHeight());
}
```